# The strongest reflection principle that does not violate covering lemmas

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, large-cardinals, inner-model-theory

#-generated reflection, or Indiscernible-generation, is considered to be the strongest reflection principle that does not violate the covering lemma in L. [1]

Is there a way to extend this success to other inner/core models has covering lemmas proofs? (like $L(R), L[U], ...$)

---

[1] Friedman, S.-D. and Honzik, R. (2016), "[On strong forms of reflection in set theory](https://www1.cuni.cz/%7Ehonzikr/papers/reflection_revised_MLQ.pd)". Math. Log. Quart., 62: 52-58, DOI:[10.1002/malq.201400047](https://doi.org/10.1002/malq.201400047), [MR3472179](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=3472179), [Zbl 1357.03084](https://zbmath.org/1357.03084).